# Trouble accessing python modules in Canopy?

Tags: python-2.7, package, canopy

I'm having trouble getting modules to be visible to python in Canopy. Specifically, in the python code in file opened in Canopy, I get an error "No Module named ----- " 
After reading several other answers on stackoverflow, I did used the terminal command "export PATH=/Users/TheSlothQueen/Library/Enthought/Canopy_32bit/User/bin:${PATH}". (to make Canopy the default python environment, as far as I understand). And this has worked, because now if I type start python in terminal and "import sys" then "sys.prefix", Enthought Canopy is indeed shown as the python path.

Following these (https://support.enthought.com/hc/en-us/articles/204469690-Installing-packages-into-Canopy-User-Python-from-the-OS-command-line ) instructions, I should now be able to use the enpkg command instead of pip install. However,this requires I log in to canopy and I don't think I have a membership.

What can I do instead? Before I changed the default python path to Canopy's environment, I could install openpyxl into Library/Python/2.7/site-packages and it was clearly present, but the "import openpyxl" command in my python file in Canopy could still not access it.

I'm not very good at using the command line and am new to Canopy, but am fairly experienced in python. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use `enpkg` or register for a free Canopy account:

Set up a `.pth` file in your Canopy `site-packages` `/Users/TheSlothQueen/Library/Enthought/Canopy_32bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages` that contains the path to your regular python `site-packages`. See https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/59012/how-to-access-esri-arcpy-modules-from-enthought-canopy/59144#59144

Comment: That makes sense. Apparently I don't have any Enthought folder in Library. Do I need to create one there?

Comment: I strongly discourage you from taking this approach, which will result in a fragile configuration. Alternate answer coming.

Answer (score 0):

1) As a rule you should never copy or link between Python distributions, which can lead to unexplained crashes and other bugs due to incompatible dependencies. Instead, each Python distribution should be self-contained. There are rare situations when you have no alternative (such as the ArcGIS example referred to in @TheoretiCAL's answer), but only as a last resort.

So if you want to install the same package into more than one Python distribution (e.g. to use openpyxl in both your system python and in Canopy Python), you should install it independently into each distribution. I'll describe this in a moment, but first it is worth tangentially mentioning a different case -- that if you are developing your own code (or using a colleague's code) in a directory outside of either Python distribution, then you can set your PYTHONPATH environment variable to that directory, which will allow you to access it from either Python distribution, usually safely.

2) Since you say you're not very comfortable at the command line, why not just install openpyxl from Canopy's Package Manager? Except for a few edge cases with troubling dependencies, this is equivalent to using `enpkg`.

3) To log into Canopy or for enpkg, registering an account is free: https://enthought.com/accounts/login/

4) If you *do* want to install your package from the command line, the article you cited is good. Note that the easiest way to make Canopy your default Python in a Terminal is to open a Canopy Terminal from the Canopy Tools menu. For other ways, see [this article](https://support.enthought.com/hc/en-us/articles/204469730-Make-Canopy-User-Python-be-your-default-Python-i-e-on-the-PATH-).